# When do Poisson and negative binomial regressions fit the same coefficients?

Tags: regression, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression

I’ve noticed that in R, Poisson and negative binomial (NB) regressions always seem to fit the same coefficients for categorical, but not continuous, predictors.

For example, here's a regression with a categorical predictor:

```
data(warpbreaks)
library(MASS)

rs1 = glm(breaks ~ tension, data=warpbreaks, family="poisson")
rs2 = glm.nb(breaks ~ tension, data=warpbreaks)

#compare coefficients
cbind("Poisson"=coef(rs1), "NB"=coef(rs2))
```

[image]

Here is an example with a continuous predictor, where the Poisson and NB fit different coefficients:

```
data(cars)
rs1 = glm(dist ~ speed, data=cars, family="poisson")
rs2 = glm.nb(dist ~ speed, data=cars)

#compare coefficients
cbind("Poisson"=coef(rs1), "NB"=coef(rs2))
```

[image]

(Of course these aren't count data, and the models aren't meaningful...)

Then I recode the predictor into a factor, and the two models again fit the same coefficients:

```
library(Hmisc)
speedCat = cut2(cars$speed, g=5) 
#you can change g to get a different number of bins

rs1 = glm(cars$dist ~ speedCat, family="poisson")
rs2 = glm.nb(cars$dist ~ speedCat)

#compare coefficients
cbind("Poisson"=coef(rs1), "NB"=coef(rs2))
```

[image]

However, Joseph Hilbe’s *Negative Binomial Regression* gives an example (6.3, pg 118-119) where a categorical predictor, sex, is fit with slightly different coefficients by the Poisson ($b=0.883$) and NB ($b=0.881$). He says: “The incidence rate ratios between the Poisson and NB models are quite similar. This is not surprising given the proximity of $\alpha$ [corresponding to $1/\theta$ in R] to zero.”

I understand this, but in the above examples, `summary(rs2)` tells us that $\theta$ is estimated at 9.16 and 7.93 respectively.

So why are the coefficients exactly the same? And why only for categorical predictors?

---

### Edit #1

Here is an example with two non-orthogonal predictors. Indeed, the coefficients are no longer the same:

```
data(cars)

#make random categorical predictor
set.seed(1); randomCats1 = sample( c("A","B","C"), length(cars$dist), replace=T)
set.seed(2); randomCats2 = sample( c("C","D","E"), length(cars$dist), replace=T)

rs1 = glm(dist ~ randomCats1 + randomCats2, data=cars, family="poisson")
rs2 = glm.nb(dist ~ randomCats1 + randomCats2, data=cars)

#compare coefficients
cbind("Poisson"=coef(rs1), "NB"=coef(rs2))
```

[image]

And, including another predictor causes the models to fit different coefficients even when the new predictor is continuous. So, it is something to do with the orthogonality of the dummy variables I created in my original example?

```
rs1 = glm(dist ~ randomCats1 + speed, data=cars, family="poisson")
rs2 = glm.nb(dist ~ randomCats1 + speed, data=cars)

#compare coefficients
cbind("Poisson"=coef(rs1), "NB"=coef(rs2))
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Nice question. I will try to write something up for you in a few hours. In the meantime, you might try and see what happens with multiple categorical predictors that are not orthogonal (hint!).

Comment: Intrigue! I will definitely try that. And thank you, I eagerly look forward to your answer.

Comment: Sorry @half-pass; I have not forgotten about this and will try to get something up within a day. (I have half an answer put together, but have gotten pulled away by other tasks.) Hopefully the bounty will also attract other answers. Cheers. :-)

Comment: No worries, @cardinal! I know you and all the other amazing gurus here have lives outside CV :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**You have discovered an intimate, but generic, property of GLMs fit by maximum likelihood**. The result drops out once one considers the simplest case of all: Fitting a *single* parameter to a *single* observation!

**One sentence answer**: If all we care about is fitting separate means to disjoint subsets of our sample, then GLMs will always yield $\hat\mu_j = \bar y_j$ for each subset $j$, so the actual error structure and parametrization of the density both become irrelevant to the (point) estimation!

**A bit more**: Fitting orthogonal categorical factors by maximum likelihood is equivalent to fitting separate means to disjoint subsets of our sample, so this explains why Poisson and negative binomial GLMs yield the same parameter estimates. Indeed, the same happens whether we use Poisson, negbin, Gaussian, inverse Gaussian or Gamma regression (see below). In the Poisson and negbin case, the *default* link function is the $\log$ link, but that is a red herring; while this yields the same *raw* parameter estimates, we'll see below that this property really has nothing to do with the link function at all.

When we are interested in a parametrization with more structure, or that depends on continuous predictors, then the assumed error structure becomes relevant due to the mean-variance relationship of the distribution as it relates to the parameters and the nonlinear function used for modeling the conditional means.

**GLMs and exponential dispersion families: Crash course**

An *exponential dispersion family* in natural form is one such that the log density is of the form
$$
\log f(y;\,\theta,\nu) = \frac{\theta y - b(\theta)}{\nu} + a(y,\nu) \>.
$$

Here $\theta$ is the *natural parameter* and $\nu$ is the *dispersion parameter*. If $\nu$ were known, this would just be a standard one-parameter exponential family. All the GLMs considered below assume an error model from this family.

Consider a sample of a *single* observation from this family. If we fit $\theta$ by maximum likelihood, we get that $y = b'(\hat\theta)$, irrespective of the value of $\nu$. This readily extends to the case of an iid sample since the log likelihoods add, yielding $\bar y = b'(\hat\theta)$.

But, we also know, due to the nice regularity of the log density as a function of $\theta$, that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \mathbb E \log f(Y;\theta,\nu) = \mathbb E \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log f(Y;\theta,\nu) = 0 \>.
$$
So, in fact $b'(\theta) = \mathbb E Y = \mu$.

Since maximum likelihood estimates are invariant under transformations, this means that
$
\bar y = \hat\mu 
$
for this family of densities.

Now, in a GLM, we model $\mu_i$ as $\mu_i = g^{-1}(\mathbf x_i^T \beta)$ where $g$ is the link function. But if $\mathbf x_i$ is a vector of all zeros except for a single 1 in position $j$, then $\mu_i = g(\beta_j)$. The likelihood of the GLM then factorizes according to the $\beta_j$'s and we proceed as above. This is precisely the case of orthogonal factors.

**What's so different about continuous predictors?**

When the predictors are continuous or they are categorical, but cannot be reduced to an orthogonal form, then the likelihood no longer factors into individual terms with a separate mean depending on a separate parameter. At this point, the error structure and link function *do* come into play.

If one cranks through the (tedious) algebra, the likelihood equations become
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(y_i - \mu_i)x_{ij}}{\sigma_i^2}\frac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial \lambda_i} = 0\>,
$$
for all $j = 1,\ldots,p$ where $\lambda_i = \mathbf x_i^T \beta$. Here, the $\beta$ and $\nu$ parameters enter implicitly through the link relationship $\mu_i = g(\lambda_i) = g(\mathbf x_i^T \beta)$ and variance $\sigma_i^2$.

In this way, the link function and assumed error model become relevant to the estimation.

**Example: The error model (almost) doesn't matter**

In the example below, we generate negative binomial random data depending on three categorical factors. Each observation comes from a single category and the same dispersion parameter ($k = 6$) is used.

We then fit to these data using five different GLMs, each with a $\log$ link: (**a**) negative binomial, (**b**) Poisson, (**c**) Gaussian, (**d**) Inverse Gaussian and (**e**) Gamma GLMs. All of these are examples of exponential dispersion families.

From the table, we can see that the parameter estimates are *identical*, even though some of these GLMs are for discrete data and others are for continuous,and some are for nonnegative data while others are not.

```
      negbin  poisson gaussian invgauss    gamma
XX1 4.234107 4.234107 4.234107 4.234107 4.234107
XX2 4.790820 4.790820 4.790820 4.790820 4.790820
XX3 4.841033 4.841033 4.841033 4.841033 4.841033
```

The caveat in the heading comes from the fact that the fitting procedure will fail if the observations don't fall within the domain of the particular density. For example, if we had $0$ counts randomly generated in the data above, then the Gamma GLM would fail to converge since Gamma GLMs require strictly positive data.

**Example: The link function (almost) doesn't matter**

Using the same data, we repeat the procedure fitting the data with a Poisson GLM with three different link functions: (**a**) $\log$ link, (**b**) identity link and (**c**) square-root link. The table below shows the coefficient estimates after converting back to the log parameterization. (So, the second column showns $\log(\hat \beta)$ and the third shows $\log(\hat \beta^2)$ using the raw $\hat\beta$ from each of the fits). Again, the estimates are identical.

```
> coefs.po
         log       id     sqrt
XX1 4.234107 4.234107 4.234107
XX2 4.790820 4.790820 4.790820
XX3 4.841033 4.841033 4.841033
```

The caveat in the heading simply refers to the fact that the *raw* estimates will vary with the link function, but the implied mean-parameter estimates will not.

**R code**

```
# Warning! This code is a bit simplified for compactness.
library(MASS)
n <- 5
m <- 3
set.seed(17)
b <- exp(5+rnorm(m))
k <- 6

# Random negbin data; orthogonal factors
y <- rnbinom(m*n, size=k, mu=rep(b,each=n))
X <- factor(paste("X",rep(1:m,each=n),sep=""))

# Fit a bunch of GLMs with a log link
con <- glm.control(maxit=100)
mnb <- glm(y~X+0, family=negative.binomial(theta=2))
mpo <- glm(y~X+0, family="poisson")
mga <- glm(y~X+0, family=gaussian(link=log), start=rep(1,m), control=con)
miv <- glm(y~X+0, family=inverse.gaussian(link=log), start=rep(2,m), control=con)
mgm <- glm(y~X+0, family=Gamma(link=log), start=rep(1,m), control=con)    
coefs <- cbind(negbin=mnb$coef, poisson=mpo$coef, gaussian=mga$coef
                   invgauss=miv$coef, gamma=mgm$coef)

# Fit a bunch of Poisson GLMs with different links.
mpo.log  <- glm(y~X+0, family=poisson(link="log"))
mpo.id   <- glm(y~X+0, family=poisson(link="identity"))
mpo.sqrt <- glm(y~X+0, family=poisson(link="sqrt"))   
coefs.po <- cbind(log=mpo$coef, id=log(mpo.id$coef), sqrt=log(mpo.sqrt$coef^2))
```

Comment: +1, clear and comprehensive, a better answer than what I gave.

Comment: @mpr, I would much prefer to think of it as complementary to yours. I was very pleased when I saw your post; you've clearly and concisely described (and shown) what's going on. My posts sometimes get a little long to read; I fear this is one of them.

Comment: You are both amazing. Thank you so much for explaining this to me with such clarity and rigor. I need to spend some more time digesting now :)

Comment: @cardinal Where did you get the  2 in "`family=negative.binomial(theta=2)`" from?

Answer (score 25):

In order to see what is going on here, it is useful first to do the regression without the intercept, since an intercept in a categorical regression with just one predictor is meaningless:

```
> rs1 = glm(breaks ~ tension-1, data=warpbreaks, family="poisson")
> rs2 = glm.nb(breaks ~ tension-1, data=warpbreaks)
```

Since Poisson and negative binomial regressions specify the log of the mean parameter, then for categorical regression, exponentiating the coefficients will give you the actual mean parameter for each category:

```
>  exp(cbind("Poisson"=coef(rs1), "NB"=coef(rs2)))
          Poisson       NB
tensionL 36.38889 36.38889
tensionM 26.38889 26.38889
tensionH 21.66667 21.66667
```

These parameters correspond to the actual means over the different category values:

```
> with(warpbreaks,tapply(breaks,tension,mean))
       L        M        H 
36.38889 26.38889 21.66667
```

So what is happening is that the mean parameter $\lambda$ in each case that maximizes likelihood is equal to the sample mean for each category.

For Poisson distribution it is clear why this occurs. There is only one parameter to fit, and thus maximizing the overall likelihood of a model with a single categorical predictor is equivalent to independently finding a $\lambda$ which maximizes likelihood for the observations in each particular category.  The maximum likelihood estimator for the Poisson distribution is simply the sample mean, which is why the regression coefficients are precisely the (logs of the) sample means for each category.

For negative binomial it is not quite as simple, because there are two parameters to fit: $\lambda$ and the shape parameter $\theta$.  Moreover, the regression fits a single $\theta$ that covers the whole dataset, so in this situation a categorical regression is not simply equivalent to fitting a completely separate model for each category.  However, by examining the likelihood function, we can see that for any given theta, the likelihood function is again be maximized by setting $\lambda$ to the sample mean:

\begin{align}
L(X,\lambda,\theta) &= \prod \left(\frac{\theta}{\lambda+\theta}\right)^\theta
\frac{\Gamma(\theta + x_i)}{x_i!\Gamma(\theta)}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\theta}\right)^{x_i}\\
\log L(X,\lambda,\theta) &= 
\sum\theta\left(\text{log}\theta-\text{log}(\lambda+\theta)\right)
+x_i\left(\text{log}\lambda-\text{log}(\lambda+\theta)\right)
+\log\left(\frac{\Gamma(\theta + x_i)}{x_i!\Gamma(\theta)}\right)\\
\frac{d}{d\lambda}\log L(X,\lambda,\theta) &= 
\sum \frac{x_i}{\lambda}-\frac{\theta+x_i}{\lambda+\theta}
=n\left(\frac{\bar{x}}{\lambda}-\frac{\bar{x}+\theta}{\lambda+\theta}\right),
\end{align}
so the maximum is attained when $\lambda=\bar{x}$.

The reason that you don't get the same coefficients for continuous data is because in a continuous regression, $\text{log}(\lambda)$ is no longer going to be a piecewise constant function of the predictor variables, but a linear one.   Maximizing the likelihood function in this case will not reduce to independently fitting a value $\lambda$ for disjoint subsets of the data, but will rather be a nontrivial problem that is solved numerically, and is likely to produce different results for different likelihood functions.

Similarly, if you have multiple categorical predictors, despite the fact that the fitted model will ultimately specify $\lambda$ as a piecewise constant function, in general there will not be enough degrees of freedom to allow $\lambda$ to be determined independently for each constant segment.  For example, suppose that you have $2$ predictors with $5$ categories each.  In this case, your model has $10$ degrees of freedom, whereas there are $5*5=25$ unique different combinations of the categories, each of which will have its own fitted value of $\lambda$.  So, assuming that the intersections of these categories are non-empty (or at least that $11$ of them are nonempty), the likelihood maximization problem again becomes nontrivial and will generally produce different outcomes for Poisson versus negative binomial or any other distribution.

Comment: (+1) Good answer. One thing that I think could be drawn out more explicitly here is that this really has nothing to do with any relationship between the Poisson and the negative binomial, but rather more basic facts about fitting GLMs via maximum likelihood.

Comment: Good point.  The only real thing Poisson and negative binomial have to do with it is that they are specified by the log of the mean parameter.  For example, if you did an ordinary least squares regression, the coefficients would be nominally different because then the parameter would the actual mean rather than the log.

Comment: True, but I think it goes a little beyond that: Fit *any* GLM using *any* link function (by ML, and with very minor caveats) and because the fitted means will match the sample means, then the parameter estimates are identical up to the nonlinear transformation between different links. The specific error model is irrelevant beyond the fact that it comes from an exponential dispersion family.

Comment: This is a good point that I did not cover.  I approached this question from the more general point of view of ML estimation, rather than GLMs specifically.  There are plenty of naturally occuring models where ML will produce fitted means that differ from sample means (e.g. lognormal).  But for GLMs, your observation leads to a more concise and more general explanation.

Comment: @cardinal: I'm confused about the generalization to any GLM and any link function. I fit a simple Gaussian LM to the warpbreaks data and found that the coefficients were different from the exponentiated coefficients of the Poisson and NB.

Comment: @half-pass: Fit all of your orthogonal categorical models as `y~X+0` and try again. :-)